# Can I configure jenkins to send an email with a static analysis report summary?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I'd like to send an email after a build completes with some data from the reports that are run (PMD, Checkstyle, Findbugs, Cobertura) such as number of issues, new issues, coverage etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get some data using the email-ext plugin. You need to include a jelly file in the email sent like this:

```
${JELLY_SCRIPT, template="html"}
```

There is a default template (`html.jelly`) which includes junit and Cobertura results which I've modified by adding something like this:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define">
 ...
 <j:set var="fb" value="${it.getAction('hudson.plugins.findbugs.FindBugsResultAction')}" />
  <table width="100%">
   <tr><td colspan="2"><b>Findbugs Result</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Total:</td><td>${fb.result.numberOfWarnings}</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Fixed:</td><td>${fb.result.numberOfFixedWarnings}</td></tr>
   <tr><td>New:</td><td>${fb.result.numberOfNewWarnings}</td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan="2"><a href="${rooturl}${build.url}/findbugs">View Report</a></td></tr>
</table>
 ...
</j:jelly>
```

For PMD and CheckStyle you can do something similar with:

```
<j:set var="pmd" value="${it.getAction('hudson.plugins.pmd.PmdResultAction')}" />
<j:set var="cs" value="${it.getAction('hudson.plugins.checkstyle.CheckStyleResultAction')}" />
```

I've not yet found a way to include the low/medium/high priority figures for the results.

Comment: Does this work for you? "${it.getAction('hudson.plugins.findbugs.FindBugsResultAction')}".Doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the exact markup from the working jelly file - the it.getAction bit is the same.

Comment: Remember, you have to actually generate the findbugs report using ant or maven, this will only pick up the results of that report.

Comment: Yes yes. Reports are generated as part of maven build.

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is a ````static-analysis.jelly```` for specifically this purpose. You might want to try that as well. Its available at ````$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/email-ext/WEB-INF/classes/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates````

Answer (score 2):

```
<j:set var="pmd" value="${it.getAction('hudson.plugins.pmd.PmdResultAction')}" />
<j:if test="${pmd.isEmpty()!=true}">
   <TABLE width="100%">
       <TR><TD colspan="2" class="bg1"><B>PMD Result</B></TD></TR>
      <tr><td>Total:</td><td>${pmd.result.numberOfWarnings}</td></tr>
      <tr><td>High:</td><td>${pmd.result.getNumberOfAnnotations('HIGH')}</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Normal:</td><td>${pmd.result.getNumberOfAnnotations('NORMAL')}</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Low:</td><td>${pmd.result.getNumberOfAnnotations('LOW')}</td></tr>
      <tr><td>New:</td><td>${pmd.result.numberOfNewWarnings}</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Fixed:</td><td>${pmd.result.numberOfFixedWarnings}</td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2"><a href="${rooturl}${build.url}/pmdResult/">View Report</a></td></tr>
   </TABLE >    
<BR/>
</j:if>
```

Have a try! More check my gist here: https://gist.github.com/yangboz/9204868

Comment: where can I see the methods available for any given plugin (i.e. cppcheck) so I can set my own template with the information I need?

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/22008267/1688570

For exact Action names look in \Jenkins\jobs\fispp-all-master\builds\${buildNumber}\build.xml file. 
I.e. I had to use hudson.plugins.findbugs.FindBugsMavenResultAction to show correct results.