# is there a way to see all the available methods of a plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am learning Jenkins on my own and I am trying to learn about plugins. I have a stage to send an email with the cppcheck results with a template I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888338/sending-cppcheck-result-report-on-email-from-jenkins-using-email-ext-plugin) the template instantiate the `CppcheckBuildAction` and access its methods, what I would like to know if is possible to check what methods are avaialable for that instance and if possible how / where I can see them.

Also how could I for example echo / println one of them. For instance in the template provided in the link above it acces the total number of errors with `${cppcheckResult.report.getNumberTotal()}` but if I echo it I get an error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: cppcheckResult for class: groovy.lang.Binding`, this is what I tried

```
        stage('Email') {
            steps {
                script{
                    publishCppcheck pattern:'cppcheck.xml'
                    emailext( subject: 'foo', to: 'mail@mail.net', body: '${JELLY_SCRIPT, template="custom"}')
                }
                echo "${cppcheckResult.report.getNumberTotal()}"
            }
        }
```

my final goal actually is to send the email just when the report find a new error so I was thinking to save the total number of errors in an external file and compare it with each build and if the number is bigger send the email, is there any native / easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most plugins should have a [javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/) link. At bottom of [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cppcheck/),should see [javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/cppcheck/)

And then there's the [Extension Index](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/extensions/) for core and plugins.

Comment: thanks for answering I can see all the available methods now, but I cannot figure out how to do is to get the value of one of those methods into a variable within my pipeline, for instance something like `totalErrors = cppcheckResult.report.getNumberTotal()` is this even possible?

Comment: I have also tried `def action = it.getAction('org.jenkinsci.plugins.cppcheck.CppcheckBuildAction')` but I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAction() on null object` I am kind of blind here...

Comment: You seem to [indicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888338/sending-cppcheck-result-report-on-email-from-jenkins-using-email-ext-plugin), you solved the implementation question. Now you also have the "where documentation aspect, so consoder marking as accepted. As for the `null object` aspect, you should test it exists before assignment. I don't use the plugin, so ...